# CodeMirror OnSelect event not working

Tags: javascript, events, codemirror

**See edit at the end**

---

I've just started to use [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) for a project and I'm facing a problem that I don't understand at all.

The problem is about to handling CodeMirror's events, specifically on the `"select"` event, since I'm handling the `"change"` event without problems I cannot guess what's happening.

Let's see some code; I'm wrapping a CodeMirror object into another object, it looks similar to this:

```
function expressionEditor(config)
{
    jQuery('#divEditor').append('<textarea id="expression"/>');

    this.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('expression'),
    {
      mode:        'custom',
      lineNumbers: true,
      extraKeys:   {'Ctrl-Space': 'autocomplete'}
    });

    this.OnChange = function(instance, object)
    {
      if (object.text[0] === '.')
      {
        CodeMirror.showHint(this.editor, CodeMirror.hint.custom);
      }
    };

    this.OnSelectHint = function(completion, Element)
    {
      alert(completion + ' : ' + Element);
    };

    CodeMirror.on(this.editor, 'change', jQuery.proxy(this.OnChange, this));

    CodeMirror.on(this.editor, 'select', jQuery.proxy(this.OnSelectHint, this));
}
```

As I said, the event `"change"` works as expected, when I write a dot into the editor it calls the function `this.OnChange` which summons the hint list, but when I navigate over the suggested hints `this.OnSelectHint` function is never called (no `alert` pops up on the navigator).

According to the [CodeMirror documentation](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events) about `"select"` event, the callback must be "*Fired when a completion is selected. Passed the completion value (string or object) and the DOM node that represents it in the menu*".

Since other events are working, I'm totally lost... any clue on what's happening?

---

#### Edit

As said by [Marijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486527/marijn), there's no `"select"` event in CodeMirror; the `"select"` event is from the `show-hint` CodeMirror Addon. Just for knowing:

- How to handle events fired by CodeMirror Addons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `"select"` event in the CodeMirror API. Thus, listening for it will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: My bad! You're right, I've missreaded the documentation, the `"select"` event is from the `hint/show-hint.js` CodeMirror Addon!, I'll edit the question to address that

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `"select"` event from `show-hint` is fired on the array of autocomplete suggestions, and not on the CodeMirror editor itself.

As described [here](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/3092), you can set event handlers on that object by wrapping your `show-hint` function. For example, using the `sql-hint` add-on:

```js
    const sqlHint = CodeMirror.hint.sql;
    CodeMirror.hint.sql = (cm, options) => {
      const result = sqlHint(cm, options);
      if (result) {
        CodeMirror.on(result, 'shown', onAutocompleteShown);
        CodeMirror.on(result, 'select', onAutocompleteSelect);
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Here `onAutocompleteShown` and `onAutocompleteSelect` are the event handlers.